# Symfony2 : redirect to referer after login successful (FOSUserBundle)

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, referer

My redirect works for logout but not for login, it stays on the login page BUT referer has the proper value (I displayed `{{ app.request.headers.get('referer') }}` in my login form).

**Security.yml**:

```
firewalls:
   main:
       pattern: ^/
       form_login:
           provider:        fos_userbundle
           csrf_provider:   security.csrf.token_manager
           use_referer:     true
           success_handler: authentication_handler
       logout:
           success_handler: authentication_handler
       anonymous: true
```

**Handler**:

```
namespace LeJardinEbene\Bundle\Form\Handler;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Logout\LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

class AuthenticationHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface, LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface
{
    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        $referer = $request->headers->get('referer');
        return new RedirectResponse($referer);
    }

    public function onLogoutSuccess(Request $request)
    {
        $referer = $request->headers->get('referer');
        return new RedirectResponse($referer);
    }
}
```

**Services.yml**:

```
services:
    authentication_handler:
        class: LeJardinEbene\Bundle\Form\Handler\AuthenticationHandler
```

Does someone know what the issue is?

**UPDATE**

As you advised me I splitted the handler in 2 :

```
class LoginAuthenticationHandler
{
public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
{
    //$referer = $request->headers->get('referer');
    $referer = $event->getRequest()->headers->get('referer');
    return new RedirectResponse($referer);
}
}


class LogoutAuthenticationHandler implements LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface
{
public function onLogoutSuccess(Request $request)
{
    $referer = $request->headers->get('referer');
    return new RedirectResponse($referer);
}
}


services:
login_authentication_handler:
    class: LeJardinEbene\Bundle\Form\Handler\LoginAuthenticationHandler
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.interactive_login, method: onSecurityInteractiveLogin }

logout_authentication_handler:
    class: LeJardinEbene\Bundle\Form\Handler\LogoutAuthenticationHandler
```

But now I get the following error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException' with message 'Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler::__construct() must implement interface Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface, instance of LeJardinEbene\Bundle\Form\Handler\LoginAuthenticationHandler given
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
namespace LeJardinEbene\Bundle\Form\Handler;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface;

class LoginAuthenticationHandler extends AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface
{
public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
{
    $referer = $event->getRequest()->headers->get('referer');
    return new RedirectResponse($referer);
}
}
```

Produces the error :

```
Fatal error: Class LeJardinEbene\Bundle\Form\Handler\LoginAuthenticationHandler cannot extend from interface Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/symfony2/src/LeJardinEbene/Bundle/Form/Handler/LoginAuthenticationHandler.php on line 22
```

**UPDATE 3**

I already tried and it causes this error :

```
Fatal error: Class LeJardinEbene\Bundle\Form\Handler\LoginAuthenticationHandler contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface::onAuthenticationSuccess) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/symfony2/src/LeJardinEbene/Bundle/Form/Handler/LoginAuthenticationHandler.php on line 22
```

and if I do this everything has to changed no ? I mean, no more $event etc. but $request and $token again as arguments ... which didn't work when I opened this topic, arghhhhhhhhhhh !!

**UPDATE 4**

services.yml

```
services:
login_handler:
    class: LeJardinEbene\Bundle\Form\Handler\LoginAuthenticationHandler
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.interactive_login, method: onSecurityInteractiveLogin }
```

security.yml

```
firewalls:
   main:
       pattern: ^/
       form_login:
           provider:        fos_userbundle
           csrf_provider:   security.csrf.token_manager
           use_referer:     true
           success_handler: login_handler
       logout:
           success_handler: logout_authentication_handler
       anonymous: true
```

Comment: No error anymore but doesn't go back to referer ... couldn't it be because of my security.yml ? maybe it is not "success_handler: login_authentication_handler". Seems incredible it still does not work. Anyway thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Waw ... surely a mistake, try to change the name of the service in your `services.yml` and in your security at `success_handler`.
Sorry !

Comment: tried but same, please see update 4 ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement the following method in your AuthenticationHandler :

```
public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event) 
{
    $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();
}
```

It solved the problem for me.

**Update**

If adding this method doesn't solve the problem for you, add the following into :

```
$referer = $event->getRequest()->headers->get('referer');

return new RedirectResponse($referer);
```

After that, if the event is not fired, you should separate your AuthenticationHandler in two (e.g. LogoutSuccessHandler and AuthenticationHandler), declare two services and specify the event you are listening on, and which method should be called.

Example :

```
services:
    authentication_handler:
        class: LeJardinEbene\Bundle\Form\Handler\AuthenticationHandler
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.interactive_login, method: onSecurityInteractiveLogin }
```

**Update2**

[Here a gist](https://gist.github.com/chalasr/69ad35c11e38b8cc717f) including your `LoginAuthenticationHandler` and the corresponding service declaration.

Comment: See my update. Just implement it like follows make the original event correctly fired for me. But you can also do your redirection into.

Comment: Make your `LoginAuthenticationSuccessHandler` extends `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface`

Comment: I updated the error message at the end of my post, seems I had to clear the cache

Comment: Sorry change extends to implements !!

Comment: please see my answer in UPDATE 3

Answer (score 0):

Try separate the handler LeJardinEbene\Bundle\Form\Handler\AuthenticationHandler in 2 handlers, one implementing AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface and other implementing LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface. The code will be something like this:

```
<?php

namespace LeJardinEbene\Bundle\Form\Handler;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Logout\LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

class AuthenticationHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface
{
 public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
 {
  $referer = $request->headers->get('referer');
  return new RedirectResponse($referer);
 }
}

<?php

namespace LeJardinEbene\Bundle\Form\Handler;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Logout\LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

class LogoutAuthenticationHandler implements LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface
{

 public function onLogoutSuccess(Request $request)
 {
  $referer = $request->headers->get('referer');
  return new RedirectResponse($referer);
 }
}
```

Sorry my english

Comment: thank you but it doesn't change anything although I defined 2 services also, one for login, the other for logout. And updated the security.ml also; please see my update

Comment: like @chalasr commented before Make your LoginAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInte‌​rface